# Duplicate value for resource 'attr/animationMode' with config 'DEFAULT' problem

Tags: android, kotlin

when i added kotlin sdk in my java project i faced this problem:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

```
C:\Users\esmae\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\968226e282565914e6944dd746d7f052\transformed\material-1.6.1\res\values\values.xml:7098:4: Duplicate value for resource 'attr/animationMode' with config 'DEFAULT' and product ''. Resource was previously defined here: C:\Users\esmae\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\968226e282565914e6944dd746d7f052\transformed\material-1.6.1\res\values\values.xml:6408:4: .
```

value.xml

```
    <declare-styleable name="SnackbarLayout">
    <attr name="android:maxWidth"/>
    <attr name="elevation"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="maxActionInlineWidth"/>
    <!-- Sets the enter and exit animations for a Snackbar. -->
    <attr format="enum" name="animationMode">
      <!-- Mode that corresponds to the slide in and out animations. -->
      <enum name="slide" value="0"/>
      <!-- Mode that corresponds to the fade in and out animations. -->
      <enum name="fade" value="1"/>
    </attr>
  </declare-styleable>
```

app built when i renamed or removed animationMode attribute but i have error when making snackbar. any idea whats the problem?

i tried with different gradle version

delete cashes an restart

clean project

but nothing happen

Comment: did you just invalidate the cache and restart or did you actually delete the ~/.gradle/caches/  folder?

Comment: yes, I did that too, but the error still exists